# Sharepoint Datatable with export option in excel pdf and csv

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, datatable

I have created a list in sharepoint and trying to load in datatable using rest api with search and export option to tranfer in excel file for download. kindly help.

Comment: You want to load SharePoint list data in datatable https://datatables.net/ ? If you just want to export in excel then you can use out of the box ways: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-an-external-list-to-excel-fcbb5cdc-cf49-4131-8294-21bc25e66952 , or use the 'Get data' option in Excel to load it directly from SharePoint online list. Any other reason for using DataTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo to bind Rest Json to DataTable and with export option for your reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<table id="requests" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Countries</th>
            <th>Cities</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#requests').DataTable({
        'ajax': {
        'url': "https://Tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items",
        'headers': { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' },
        'dataSrc': function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            return data.value.map(function(item) {
                return [
                    item.Title,
                    item.Countries,
                    item.Cities
                    ];
            });
        }
    },
       dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

[image]

[image]